# Is it possible to Dim a variable in VB.net using values from an array?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I need to create several text files in vb.net based on values entered in a spreadsheet.  Each text file will be named 'valuename.txt'.

I populate an array with the value names as they are entered:

```
issues(j) = Grid1.Cells(1, j).Value
```

Now I need to open text files with their names.  I would like to do something along the lines of:

```
 Dim Filename As String = "C:\" & Grid1.Cells(1, j).Value & ".txt"

 Dim issues(j) As New System.IO.StreamWriter(Filename)
```

When I enter this in Visual Studio, it says it does not like:

```
 issues(j)
```

Do I have any other options?

Comment: I'm sure you can describe "it says it does not like" much better.

Comment: `System.IO.StreamWriter` returns a streamwriter object and you are trying to assign it (apparently) to a string array element.  See [StreamWriter Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter(v=vs.110).aspx) for how to use it, including sample code.

Comment: In general, you cannot `Dim issues(j)` but rather `Dim issues()`. However, if I see what you want to do, you rather want `issues()` being the array containing the file names to pass in the `StreamWriter`. So `issues()` is not a `StreamWriter`, but the array containing the input for the `StreamWriter`.

Comment: The error is:  Arrays cannot be declared with 'New'.

Comment: `issues` is already declared as a string array - you cannot assign a StreamWriter object to it or redeclare it as such - you do not need an array of `StreamWriters` anyway.  `Using sw As New StreamWriter(filename)...` is the right way as per the link.  Also, your code will likely not have permission to write to "C:\"

Comment: Thanks.  Can I do: Using issues(j) As New StreamWriter(filename)?  I think I need a unique name for each file and a unique StreamWriter.

Comment: `Array(String)` `<>` `StreamWriter` so no.

Comment: **No**.  As I have clearly said twice now, you cannot assign a StreamWriter object to a string array element.  They are 2 entirely different Types: strings are strings and StreamWriters are StreamWriter objects.  There is no need to store the SW in an array anyway, you want to dispose of it when you are done with it, not save it indefinitely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the code you have posted is inside a for loop with j being the counting variable.

You are already building a filename from the cell values, so just declare the streamwriter as a new variable and use it:

```
For j = 0 To Grid1.Rows.Count - 1 'Assumed by me

    'Create the filename for the current row
    Dim Filename As String = "C:\" & Grid1.Cells(1, j).Value & ".txt"

    'The Using block makes sure that the ressources used by the streamwriter are disposed again.
    'It is equivalent as Dim sw As New IO.Streamwriter, but Using should be preferred
    Using sw As New IO.StreamWriter(Filename)
        'Use the streamwriter to write the data
    End Using

    'If you additionally want to store the values in an array for whatever reason       
     issues(j) = Grid1.Cells(1, j).Value 
Next
```

Your `Dim issues(j)` statement does not make any sense.

To append data to an existing file, use the overload of the StreamWriter constructor:

```
Using sw As New IO.StreamWriter(Filename, True)
```

The second parameter defines if data should be added to the file.

Comment: Thanks.  I need to use the StreamWriter to write values to the unique files throughout the day.  Can I simply do "Using sw As New IO.StreamWriter(Filename) each time I need to append values to one of the files?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Using` to declare a new StreamWriter:

```
 Dim Filename As String = "C:\" & Grid1.Cells(1, j).Value & ".txt"

 Using fsw As New System.IO.StreamWriter(Filename)
     'Do Something
 End Using
```

But if you insist to use a list of StreamWriter (I don't know why) then you can do something like this:

```
Dim fsw As New List(Of System.IO.StreamWriter)
fsw(j) = New System.IO.StreamWriter(Filename)
'Do Something
fsw(j).Close
fsw(j).Dispose
```